# DNSCrypt for specific programs only possible?

Tags: networking, windows-8.1, dns

Is it possible to use encrypted DNS for specific programs only?

I would like to install DNSCrypt but not for the whole pc. Not for a specific Interface. But only for specific programs, e.g. only Firefox.

Is this somehow possible? To have two browsers in parallel, Firefox and Chrome, FF using DNSCrypt, Chrome not?

Windows 8.1 x64

Comment: You could but it would be non trivial to do for several apps.   In a nutshell you install Dnscrypt systemwide and in those programs that you wish not to use it you go in proxy settings,  and tell that program in your example Chrome to NOT auto-detect / use the system proxy but some outer port or ip:port proxy.